# Comparing cell values within rows of a Data.Frame - Puzzeling Output

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a Data.Frame I joined using full_join() from dplyr. It looks like this:

```
View(df1)

Gene Pval   Pval2
ZIC3 0.4123 0.4124
GLA  *NA*   0.135
AFF2 0.003  *NA*
...  ...    ...
```

I want to pull all the Genes where Pval != Pval2 so I used

```
DF2 <- DF1[DF1$Pval != DF1$Pval2, ]
```

This has pulled out mismatching records (**294**) but DF2 also contains **38** additional rows that are all `NA` despite the fact that DF1 does not contain any full `NA` rows. (**332 total**)

Similarly, if I do

```
DF3 <- DF1[DF1$Pval == DF1$Pval2, ]
```

DF3 has **37** `NA` rows. (**13,711** non empty, for **13,748** total)

DF1, the original, has **14042** rows.

The question is, I do not understand where these empty rows are coming from and why the numbers in DF2, DF3 do not add up to DF1......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also include a condition with `is.na`

```
 DF1[(DF1$Pval != DF1$Pval2) | (is.na(DF1$Pval) |is.na(DF1$Pval2)), ]
```

---

One issue that could result is when we do the comparison on floating points as the precision can be different and results in unexpected output.  It may be better to `round` and compare

```
DF1[(round(DF1$Pval, 2) != round(DF1$Pval2, 2)) | 
         (is.na(DF1$Pval) | is.na(DF1$Pval2)), ]
```

Comment: oh ok. let me try that. MY MAIN CONCERN WAS THE MISMATCHING NUMBERS BUT THAT COULD BE SOLVED BY THIS.
sorry for caps

Comment: I guess my only concern is that if a value was NA in one analysis, and not NA in another, that is still a difference and would want to pull that record

Comment: @SkyScraper in that case use `|` instead of `&` updated the post

Comment: rounding maybe an issue and that would be an important counter measure, but I am now having an issue that one of the columns is showing scientific notation while the other is not, despite changing both to numeric using "as.numeric"

Comment: @SkyScraper that you can change with `options(scipen = 999)`.  It is a print formatting issue

Comment: why is one column changed and the other not? so annoying.

Comment: @SkyScraper It may be because after the subset, one of the column may have more precision digits and other not.  So, it triggered the scientific notation in one and not other in printing

Comment: right now its reading 0.75668000 and 0.7566800000000 and calling it different (after I rounded) and changed scipen=999. let me recreate the tables

Comment: @SkyScraper Your original data column is not rounded and so it shows the precision.  If you need to have only couple of digits,, either format or round

Comment: ok I finally got it. let me look at this and summarize what I learned here